# JOOQ DSL using SqlConnection

Tags: jooq, vert.x

I am using [AsyncSQLClient](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/asyncsql/AsyncSQLClient.html) to get an async. connection to my database in vertx. Now i am struggling how to use JOOQs DSL. I am trying the following:

```
client.getConnection(res -> {
    if (res.succeeded()) {
          SQLConnection connection = res.result();

           DSL dsl = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_4);

           connection.close();
           client.close();
    } else {
    }
});
```

That is not working because using needs a Connection and not an SQLConnection. Is there any way to use an SQLConnection with JOOQ? Is there any other way to create an async connection for JOOQ?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't use JOOQ with the Vert.x AsyncSQL client.

But someone in the Vert.x community has created a [jOOQ CodeGenerator to create vertxified DAOs and POJOs](https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement (and open source!) a "proxy" for the vert.x [`SQLConnection`](http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.html) type. For instance, if you want to run the following vert.x method:

```java
interface SQLConnection {
    SQLConnection queryWithParams(
        String sql, 
        JsonArray params, 
        Handler<AsyncResult<ResultSet>> resultHandler
    );
}
```

Your proxy would expose a method like this instead:

```java
class jOOQSQLConnection {
    final SQLConnection delegate;
    <R extends Record> jOOQSQLConnection query(
        ResultQuery<R> sql, 
        Handler<AsyncResult<Result<R>>> resultHandler
    ) {
        wrapInjOOQSQLConnection(

            // Extract the SQL string from the jOOQ query
            delegate.query(sql.getSQL()),

            // Extract the bind variables from the jOOQ query and wrap them in the 
            // JsonArray type, as requested by vert.x 
            wrapjOOQParamsInJsonArray(sql.getBindValues()),

            // This is a handler that receives a vert.x ResultSet and wraps / transforms
            // it into a jOOQ result (which contains the <R> type for type safety)
            r -> resultHandler.handle(wrapInjOOQResult(r.result()))
        );
    }
}
```

The above probably won't work out of the box, but it gives you an idea of how to wrap things.

Comment: Sadly my knowledge about the framework is not that good to write an library. Thanks for heading me in the right direction!

Comment: @perotom: OK, no worries. Maybe, someone else who will find this question in the future can do it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection con = connection.getconnection()){

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("empreg", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtempid.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", txtempname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", txtsalary.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tell", txttell.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtaddress.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blog", txtblog.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", cmbgender.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hiredate", dtpdate.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@op", op);
                    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //If i > 0 AND op = "insert"
                    if (i > 0 && op == "insert"){

                        MessageBox.Show("1 row is  saved sucessfuly ");
                        submode.readdgv("emp", DGV2);
                        submode.autoid(txtempid, "emp");

                        txtempname.Clear();
                        txtsalary.Clear();
                        txttell.Clear();
                        txtaddress.Clear();
                        txtblog.Clear();
                        cmbgender.SelectedIndex = -1;
                        dtpdate.Value = DateTime.Now;
                        txtempname.Focus();

                    }

                    else if (i >= 0 && op == "update"){

                        MessageBox.Show("1 row is updated sucessfuly ");
                        submode.readdgv("emp", DGV2);
                        submode.autoid(txtempid, "emp");

                    }

                    else if (i >= 0 && op == "delete"){

                        MessageBox.Show("1 row is deleted sucessfuly");
                        submode.readdgv("emp", DGV2);
                        submode.autoid(txtempid, "emp");

                    }
                    else{

                        MessageBox.Show("process is failed");
                        submode.readdgv("emp", DGV2);
                        submode.autoid(txtempid, "emp");

                    }

                }
```